# URL is not valid to support in Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

URL is not supported in Kingfisher that URL contains an Arabic string. Please check URL "/image/cache/catalog/NEE/150ذهبي%20جديدة-500x500.jpg".

I have tried to debug in the library, It will returns resources empty and redirect to the below code.

```
guard let resource = resource else { 
  self.placeholder = placeholder 
  setWebURL(nil) 
  completionHandler?(nil, nil, .none, nil) 
  return .empty 
}
```

How can I prevent this issue?

*Notes*

- I have mentioned Kingfisher over here because kingfisher "Resources" does not support URL if its name in English. So, we need to pass encoded URL.

Comment: Is it really related with Kingfisher? As far as I see, you are not creating a valid url...

Comment: @ridvankucuk Yes, Its with kingfisher. I have created valid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it after encoding URL.

Swift 4.0

For Example:

```
let image_url = "/image/cache/catalog/NEE/150ذهبي%20جديدة-500x500.jpg".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
```

*Notes*
- I have mentioned Kingfisher over here because kingfisher "Resources" does not support URL if its name in English. So, we need to pass encoded URL.

Comment: This proves it had nothing to do with Kingfisher. You did have an invalid URL.

Comment: @rmaddy If URL name is in English then no need to encode URL.

Comment: Of course. You need to encode any URL that has special characters. It has nothing to do with Kingfisher. Your URL has special characters so it needs to be encoded properly.

Comment: Even if you url is in english try adding space to that string and see what happens without encoding ;) For example `www.google.com?q=hello there`